# iReport with Spring 3.1

Tags: spring, ireport

I'm trying to setup a report using "spring loaded hibernate" dataset, with iReport 4.5.

I'm using spring 3.1 and when have added the spring context folder to the iReport classpath, as well as the 3.1 jar files.

When I test the connection, I get a NoSuchMethodDef error on:
MutablePropertyValue.add(String,Object)

This was added after whatever version is in ireports module spring.jar, and apparantly that jar is being loaded instead of my spring 3.1 jars.

I have tried removing ireport's spring.jar from the classpath, and it just reappears when the app is loaded again.

I have also tried creating a spring.jar with 3.1's updated classes, and that didn't work either.

How do I work around this?  Does iReport support Spring 3.1?

Comment: Do you use maven ? Then set up an exclusion for the Jar you don't need .

Comment: Not using maven, and the issue is within iReport, not within my application.  My app isn't loading an old version of spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I faced the same problem which you are facing NoSuchMethodDef error on: MutablePropertyValue.add(String,Object)

For this problem I removed unwanted jars and kept same version of jars in iReport classpath after that problem was gone but i got another problem, when I clicked "Test" button,

**unexpected token at line 1 select address as address from Address address**

After I analyzed that this may be due to default iReport test connection table Address.
I ignored this issue and continued my implementation Finally iReport Spring loaded Hibernate Connection is working for me.

Please refer this link more details 
http://www.techpages.org/ireport/spring-loaded-hibernate-connection/2460/
Also try JSF JasperReport Spring loaded Hibernate Connection Example
http://www.techpages.org/ireport/jsf-jasper-report-ireport/2466/

I have used spring 3.1.1 jars.